# Object Variable or With block variable not set mid-loop

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

The issue I've got here is that

```
iRow = PullRange.Find(What:=a(x, 0)).Row - 1
```

Throws above mentioned error in the middle of a loop. The thing is it works for the first handful of iterations of x, but at x = 11/iRow = 30 it breaks and I've no clue why. There's nothing unique about that particular row and yet it crashes, has anyone any clue as to why?

Let me know if more info is needed.

```
Public Sub DataDump(Sql As String, PullColumn As String)
Dim a() As Variant
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim PullRange As Range
Dim DumpRange As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Set PullRange = Range(PullColumn & ":" & PullColumn)
Set DumpRange = Range("H1")


Set recs = New ADODB.Recordset

recs.Open Sql, con, adOpenDynamic


a = recs.GetRows

'a(y, x)


For x = 0 To UBound(a, 2)
  If IsNull(a(0, x)) Then GoTo none
    iRow = PullRange.Find(What:=a(0, x)).Row - 1
        If iRow = 0 Then GoTo none
    For y = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        Debug.Print a(y, x)
        If IsNull(a(y, x)) Then GoTo Err
        DumpRange.Offset(iRow, y) = a(y, x)
Err:
    Next y
none:
Next x



End Sub
```

Comment: Sidenote - Do not use jump statements. You can easily convert them into If-Else

Comment: The most likely cause is simply that your search value isn't found. You should always test for the result of `Find` being `Nothing` before trying to use it.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I've amended the Err jump but kept the none jump since it's too convenient and cleaner.

Comment: @PankajJaju Blanket statements like this aren't correct, goto has it's place and allows clean early exits and recursion.

Comment: @Rory People like you are the reason why I love this site. You were right, the issue was that the data was unclean...somehow. I've literally copied and pasted the same source data, but at some point I must have messed one of the cells up and when I tried to look it up it wouldn't allow itself to be found. Spent all night bashing my head against the wall but I didn't tipple check the data cleanliness..  Thanks.

Comment: @Zerk - Only in rare conditions you should be using jumps. If your code is like the code above, there is absolutely no need to jump. You do not want to convert your code into a [spaghetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Comment: @PankajJaju Exactly. "Do not use jump statements" "Only in rare conditions you should be using jumps". I'm not advocating liberal use of them for fear of spaghetti, but to outright rule them out was incorrect. Rory : Well identified, Occam's razor :)

Comment: @PankajJaju @Zerk If you don't mind me asking, would you say the `none` jump is redundant? I feel that an if statement to contain that would be too convoluted and ugly

Answer (score 0):

@Rory Was right. Unclean data caused the loop to break and I couldn't see the difference because the difference was minute, after inserting data set anew from the same source it fixed itself. Lesson learned.